# Dreamweaver Zip, not locating files correctly

Tags: image, hyperlink, dreamweaver

I've created a website in Dreamweaver that consists of images and pages. You can navigate through the pages via a taskbar and the images are viewable on certain pages. It all works fine on my local laptop but, when I zip the file and try to open it from my desktop computer, the text comes up but all of the images and links are broken.

Is there anyway I can fix this without restarting my whole website?

Answer (score 0):

You need to unzip your files first. That's where your problem is.